# Is it possible to see the RAM units configuration on HP ProLiant DL380 G5

Tags: configuration, memory, hp, hp-proliant

I have an HP ProLiant DL380 G5 Server in the datacenter running Windows Server 2008 R2.
I need to think about upgrading RAM on this server and decide on configuration of RAM units I am going to purchase. For that, I need to know how many RAM units are installed.

Can I do it without visiting a datacenter. Would software like AIDA64 work on such branded server as they work on workstations? Or do I need to use a special tool from HP for that?

Comment: Do you know which specific model of HP server you have? Is this a ProLiant DL360 G5? A DL380 G5?

Comment: @ewwhite, it's a DL380, sorry I didn't mention it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to run unknown software on a server then you can use a simple VBS script:

```
function getPhysicalMemory()
    dim memorystr
    set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    set memorySet = objWMI.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory")
    memorystr=""
    for each memory in memorySet
        if memorystr<>"" then
            memorystr=memorystr&"+"
        end if
        memorystr=memorystr & Round(memory.Capacity/1024/1024/1024,1)
    next
    getPhysicalMemory = memorystr
end function

MsgBox(getPhysicalMemory)
```

It would show all memory modules and their sizes, for example "2+2" - 4GB of RAM in 2 modules.

Comment: Nice alternative, upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to see the memory configuration remotely.

- You can do this from the server's [ILO2 web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7rv7.png) (or SSH interface).
- You can see this from the HP System Management Homepage, provided the HP Agents are installed.
- Use [dmidecode](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/dmidecode.htm) for Windows
- Other third party utilities.

Your server has limited RAM options. Only 8 DIMM slots, and a requirement for interleaved RAM. What is your RAM size target?

Answer (score 0):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can give you system configuration information, such as CPU model/features, mainboard configuration, GPU and RAM details.

I'm unsure if it will work on an HP server, so YMMV, but it uses low-level Windows system calls to pull information about your hardware, so there's no reason as far as I know why it wouldn't work.

Just download/install (or run standalone from a portable zip file), and click on the SPD and Memory tabs and click through the  Slot numbers to check what's currently installed. See screenshots below:

[image: CPU-Z SPD tag]